# Scattering right handed fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, fermions, spinors, helicity

Assume we have a QED like vector exchange, and I scatter only right handed electron-positron pair- ${e}_ R^+ e_R^-\to e_R^+ e_R^-$. Am I correct that

1. There is no s-channel amplitude-they cannot annihilate
2. There is only the t channel, where each vertex has the same kind of particle/antiparticle on each end(and thereby the same handedness of spinors)
3. If a right handed electron has the spinor $u_+, \bar{u}_+$, then the right handed positron has the spinor $v_+,\bar{v}_+$ in the spinor helicity notation, and we don't switch this to $v_-$.($u_+$ is positive helicity(say $R$) incoming fermion, $v_+$ is positive helicity outgoing anti-fermion. $u_-, v_-$ and the barred spinors are defined in an obvious manner, and we have crossing symmetry $u_{\pm}=v_{\mp}$. Am I correct in saying that an outgoing $e^+_{R}$ comes with a spinor $v_+$, or do I consider this to be a negative helicity $v_{-}$?).
4. Does it make sense to call this 'opposite helicity scattering'? Don't the positron and electron have the same helicity here(their spinors have opposite helicity, sure; but I'm not sure if this is what people usually call opposite helicity scattering)

Comment: Hi @CosmasZachos 1. So you're saying the s-channel amplitude is nonzero(I know that the full amplitude is nonzero)? I find this puzzling because for eg in $e^+ e^−→μ^+ μ^−$
there's only the s channel and the only nonzero contributions come from $e^+_Le^−_R$, nothing comes from $e^+_Re^- _R$ etc. So why would there be an $s$ channel here. I'd love for you to elaborate on this as I am very confused. I believe the full amplitude is indeed nonzero, but only from the t channel.

Comment: My bad. Apologies,  I misled you. The helicity amp for annihilation does not vanish, in general, if the vertex were allowed, but, for vector-like QED, there is no $e^+_R e^-_R γ$ coupling.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you. So, just to confirm, I am right about 1. and 2. in my post? Can you tell me something about 3. and 4.?

Comment: You are right about 1,2. I won't comment on the rest, as your statement is not clear, and I am not familiar with blanket usage, without explicitly specifying what one means.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I edited the question, see if you can help now? Thanks a lot anyways!